# how to allow namespacing for only few classes in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridster

I'm using the gridster plugin: http://gridster.net/ and also bootstrap for the layout of my dashboard. However I face issues while resizing the window. I'm using the following function for resize:

```
 var resizeTimer;
        jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                var newDashboardWidth = this.newDashboardWidth = $('#gridsterContainer').width();               
                var newbaseWidths = (newDashboardWidth) * (1- margin_ratio)/cols
                gridster.resize_widget_dimensions({
                    widget_base_dimensions: [newbaseWidths]
                });
            },200);
            });
```

With this i'm able to resize the contents on window shriking, however if when i expanding the window the contents dont go back to their normal state.My guess is the bootstrap css and gridster css have some conflicting classes that cause this issue. Is there any way I fix this? Also one way I was thinking was to provide name-spacing to the bootstrap classes, that way for nay conflicting classes, the window resize would not get affected.Any ideas on how can add name-spacing to the only those classes that cause the issue. Below is the css for boostsrap:

```
.pre-scrollable {max-height: 340px; overflow-y: scroll;}
.container { padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.container { width: 750px;}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.container {width: 970px;}
```

In the  above ex: I'd like to add the namespacing only to the media queries. Rest all the classes remain the same. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hmm...you could try recompiling the bootstrap source with LESS and scoping out what you need to a specific class. I'll try to find the post I saw on that before..

Comment: I'm not sure how would the recompiling boostrap css help me get the required classes namespaced..I tried, but in vain :(.May be i'm doing something wrong. that would be my next question on this post..